# What I believe to be a corrupt node.js file on chrome os

Tags: javascript, file, discord, discord.js, corrupt

Good day.

I'm having an issue that I have no idea how it originated or how I could solve it.

I had a node.js window open in the background while using my chromebook as a server for my discord bot. While I was using it, however, it suddenly crashed. So I reboot it, log in, and look back at my file, and it has all these crazy diamond-question mark symbols and whatnot. I don't know what caused this crash nor this file to (I think) corrupt, but I would really like to save this file and I thought maybe the gods of the internet could help me save my bot.

Full corrupt code here: https://pastebin.com/eJavAMsb

First few lines (Please look on pastebin): `ǫ"c��%DSM�-��W~��،bb�+���ǻ�C�C����Z��w�b���
��>f��Ux$�'��z�L��/_��|0G��(����)���>��
���e�3>N��3nej��%o=:��  �`?�2�-�9i��}I1u���߾@�e1U�ѐܛRr�6Sez(A�Hi�(�p�5n<�Ap����H��t��s��M�����^�RuJ_^[���P�lB��M��Tv�����8�f˷�쥢 Ra�J���7��'My�w��u�ϯ'��H�[Jf�t9;�&�[�1  ��A���<�o�h�{�>�VF2� �]�*z��b>+I�U��R�w��H�v��&}Xv�����fss�М����5E2�2�`9���f��u��I�f�\�r�W���;׷�h�*'���9�`�t��k��i��r�n�`K���a�c�!%�o��GI��m�\��J�@ ]0D�F@���P��:�4��F�H3g)tV�)������a�9!<�d�C~�s�],���q�k�L]�%��qI�yep�_,�|�S��v3Q�\��2;z���@�ͦ��������_Q���^F�!���k�#����b�bW#p~7r�İn�C���t�3B�}W�n�sl�er@~��,��h��)�)�~ͽ�Xk���:�u�K%�吒t������{��e���J���7�؎����w�ߓ�!)�.�j�#�`

Comment: Do you know what the file's contents was before it got corrupted? Also, please remove the expletives in your post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, didn't know. I do have a backup of the file from late october, but I have done so much work on the current one that I didn't think it would matter. This is the full code of the backup from october: https://pastebin.com/dkxSbidg